# how to scan a text in a folder using dirent header in C

Tags: c, dirent.h

I need to find a way to scan a folder- (for example -C:\Users\User\Documents\HW) and check if there is some text that I get from the user. I need to return which files have the exact same text. I never used dirent.h before and I have no idea how I to work with it;

Comment: The idea is to use `opendir` on the directory path, then loop with `readdir` to find all files and for each file you will probably also have to `open`, `read` and `close`. You could also for each file use `fopen`, `fread` and `fclose`. Once done you should also call `closedir`.

Comment: Please just do some research yourself before asking the world for help. Thank you.

Comment: thank you Henrik! and guess what, alk, I tried. and failed. so whats wrong with "asking the world to help"? this is a website for questions and answers!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define your own `error` function which handles errors:

```
// Standard error function
void fatal_error(const char* message) {

  perror(message);
  exit(1);
}
```

Traverse function basically stat current file, if that file is directory, we will enter that directory. In directory itself very important is to check if current directory is . or .. because this can lead into infinitive loop.

```
void traverse(const char *pathName){

  /* Fetching file info */
  struct stat buffer;
  if(stat(pathName, &buffer) == -1)
    fatalError("Stat error\n");

  /* Check if current file is regular, if it is regular, this is where you 
     will see if your files are identical. Figure out way to do this! I'm 
     leaving this part for you. 
  */

  /* However, If it is directory */
  if((buffer.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR){

    /* We are opening directory */
    DIR *directory = opendir(pathName);
    if(directory == NULL)
      fatalError("Opening directory error\n");

    /* Reading every entry from directory */
    struct dirent *entry;
    char *newPath = NULL;
    while((entry = readdir(directory)) != NULL){

      /* If file name is not . or .. */
      if(strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") && strcmp(entry->d_name, "..")){

        /* Reallocating space for new path */
        char *tmp = realloc(newPath, strlen(pathName) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 2);
        if(tmp == NULL)
          fatalError("Realloc error\n");
        newPath = tmp;

        /* Creating new path as: old_path/file_name */
        strcpy(newPath, pathName);
        strcat(newPath, "/");
        strcat(newPath, entry->d_name);

        /* Recursive function call */
        traverse(newPath);
      }
    }
    /* Since we always reallocate space, this is one memory location, so we free that memory*/
    free(newPath);

    if(closedir(directory) == -1)
      fatalError("Closing directory error\n");
  }

}
```

You can also do this using `chdir()` function, it is maybe easier that way, but I wanted to show you this way, since it is very ilustrating. But easiest way to traverse trough folder/file hierarchy is `NFTW` function. Make sure you check that in `man` pages.

If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you so so much Aleksandar!!!